# What are the possible perfect illumination conditions for 3D reconstruction using stereo cameras?

Tags: 3d, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction, disparity-mapping

I am trying to create a 3D point cloud using two 2D stereo images. The cameras and stereo is calibrated and the RMS error is 0.8 px. The baseline is 70 mm and maximum depth to be measured is 300 mm.
For stereo matching, SGBM is used. The disparity map is also not that great. What I have observed is that the 3D reconstruction appears different if the lighting conditions are changed. For instance, if the images are captured in the morning at 9 or at 2 in the afternoon, although the SGBM parameters are constant, the point cloud appear very different.
Please enlighten me if the lighting conditions are to be controlled to avoid interference of ambient light? Is there a way to get the same point cloud although lighting conditions change?

The Dataset (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M6_SQ58kEClVsYYNkYuIYUwHr3kQtO9r?usp=sharing) is organized as below:
E-Con Camera <> Left and Right Hand Images
SmartPhone Camera <> Left and Right Plant Images
While Smartphone images create a decent pointcloud, E-Con images pointcloud change throughout the day as ambient light changes (keeping SGBM parameters constant).

I tried out with multiple DC lights to illuminate the RoI perfectly. But this didn't work that well. Also, it takes a good amount of energy (as much as 40W of light source).
I tried to take stereo pair images at every hour in the day, the results were quite different, mostly distorted. The algorithm for 3D reconstruction works well with standard dataset.
I am using this github repo for the same: https://github.com/FlagArihant2000/stereo

Comment: Your problem is probably not in the light conditions, but in the algorithm. SGBM is a local method with several parameters you can play with, so you may be able to have nice results. But note that the state of the art for doing matching is by using machine learning. You may want to post some pictures to show the issue.

Comment: pictures please, or vacate the premises post haste! ;) -- illumination as such shouldn't matter, but **appearance** does. over/underexposed areas of the scene will have no texture to block-match, and may even cause spurious matches.

Comment: @decadenza I have updated the question with dataset. The images are beyond 2MB hence added Gdrive link. Also, please share the github link for disparity matching using ML. I need to try it out once too. I was also thinking of using NIR dot pattern for better feature matching (similar to those used in iphones front cam). Please elaborate about them as well..

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have updated the question with the data Gdrive link. The thing is that under varying lighting conditions, the pointcloud drastically varies, although SGBM parameters are kept constant. That made me think if illumination is an issue. Please enlighten..

Comment: all the camera pictures look sharp and appropriately illuminated. I don't see an issue yet, unless you mean the point cloud of your arm looking kinda squashed. there are some holes in it but that usually happens in ambiguous/low-texture areas.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz As long as I get a consistent point cloud in variable lighting conditions, I am fine with that, even if some information is lost. To create more features, I was thinking of using NIR dot projectors with 940nm but then the camera sensors need to be sensitive to that EM spectrum. I imaged my arm at regular intervals and with different lighting conditions and observed the 3D point cloud. Please observe the results in the GDrive link. I do observe that as the illumination changes, the point cloud changes, hence becoming highly unreliable for measurements.

Comment: One thought. The stereo images using smartphone cameras produce exceptionally good point clouds. May be because it auto adjusts all the parameters during image acquisition like exposure time, ISO, brightness, saturation, contrast, etc. Can we do the same for the E-Con cameras so that the dependency on the lighting conditions is lowered?

Comment: I still can't see much from these screenshots. it's always different perspectives and weird ones apparently. -- a common issue is both cameras not having the same settings, which includes whatever auto-exposure and auto-white balance algorithms decide to set them to. disable auto-stuff and nail those settings to something fixed and equal to both devices. you can run auto-stuff for a moment, then disable it, and if you read the settings themselves, they should reflect what the auto algorithms came up with. you can then copy that over.